# Solve $\lim_{(x, y) \to (4, 0)} x^2y \ln(x y)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I got this question:

$$\lim_{(x, y) \to (4, 0)} x^2y \ln(x y)$$

I know this limit does not exist by using Wolfram but I get 0 using all method.
How to prove this limit does not exist?

Comment: What is log(x y)? If it is $\log xy$, then the limit is $0$.

Comment: Limit exists if we approach $(4,0)$ through positive values of $y$. But the function is undefined at $(4+\delta,-\epsilon)$. Whether limit exists and is $0$ or doesn't can depend on fine details of definition.

Answer (score 3):

As noticed in the comments, it may be unclear how to compute your limit. In my opinion, the symbol $$\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)$$ should be always understood as $$\lim_{\substack{x \to x_0 \\ x \in \operatorname{dom}f}}f(x),$$ where of course $\operatorname{dom}f$ denotes the domain of $f$, and $x_0$ must be an accumulation point of this domain.
In our case, since $x$ lies near $4$, we should request $y>0$ for $\log (xy)$ to be defined. But then 
$$
\lim_{\substack{(x,y) \to (4,0) \\ y>0}} x^2 y \log (xy) = \lim_{\substack{(x,y) \to (4,0) \\ y>0}} x \left(xy \log (xy) \right) = 4 \cdot 0 = 0.
$$
I don't believe that we should claim (for instance) that

> $\lim_{x \to 0} \log x$ does not exists because $\log x$ is undefined when $x<0$.

This is a typical high-school trap that we shouldn't encourage too much: students might get convinced that mathematics is just a discipline in which you waste time after trivial things. There are situations where a stiff approach leads to useless conclusions.